# Don't show the same div in random fadeIn/Out one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JS which picks out a random div from a "list" of divs, shows it for a few seconds and fades it out, all in a random loop.

Now logically, sometimes the same div is picked directly one after another. I want to prevent this. The best case would be, if the JS would process all divs of the list in a random order, before it will start a new random "round". So e.g. div no. 5 would not be shown again directly on after another.

Here is my JS:

```
var myVar;

function showDiv() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  $('.notification').eq(random).prependTo('.container').fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
  createRandomInterval();
}

function createRandomInterval() {
  setTimeout(showDiv, 500 + Math.random() * 4000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  createRandomInterval();
});
```

Here is my complete fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brapbg1h/

Comment: You might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435428/preventing-random-operation-from-returning-same-value-twice-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is store the last result, and if it lands on it, then process again.

something like this.

```
let lastResult = -1;

function getRandom() {
  const res = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  return res === lastResult ? getRandom() : res;
}

function showDiv() {
  var random = getRandom();
  lastResult = random;
  $('.notification').eq(random).prependTo('.container').fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
  createRandomInterval();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried it in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9c3z4coL/ - but same div's where still shown one after another. Sometimes they just blink, sometimes new ones come up on the first position :/

Answer (score 1):

Save the `random` to a global variable, like `lastDiv`. Check `random` against `lastDiv` and it is a match, re-run the function again.

```js
var lastDiv;

function showDiv() {
 
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  
  if(random == lastDiv) {
    console.log('random matches lastDiv, re-running.');
    return showDiv();
  }
  
  lastDiv = random;
  
  $('.notification').eq(random).prependTo('.container').fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
  createRandomInterval();
}

function createRandomInterval() {
  setTimeout(showDiv, 500 + Math.random() * 4000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  createRandomInterval();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: none;
  /* hide initially so that fadIn() fadeOut() will work */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="notification">1</div>
  <div class="notification">2</div>
  <div class="notification">3</div>
  <div class="notification">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EleazarEnrique, doesn't yours also include calling `getRandom()` *too many* times before getting an index that it is not matching the previous? You split things into two functions, while I stop function execution at the point where it doesn't satisfy the criteria.

Comment: But when I run your example, same div's where still shown one after another. E.g. div "3" where shown 3 times directly after another. :/

Answer (score 0):

## Previous Div in a variable

If you do not want 2 **consequent** divs to be the same, just assign the number of the div (since it is from a list) to a variable and if it is equal to current selection run the function again in a do..while loop.

```
var random;

function showDiv() {
    do {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
    } while(random==previousDiv);
    $('.notification').eq(random).prependTo('.container').fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
    createRandomInterval();

    var previousDiv = random;
}
```

Comment: Hey, first thank you! I put it into a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0vmb0pxt/ - what now happens is, that sometimes the same div fadesOut and fadesIn instantly, so that there is something like a flashing effect on the div. How could we avoid this and make sure that if div "5" is or was shown, the function will first pick other ones, before it picks "5" again?

Comment: Hello, you have to put the items that are VISIBLE inside an array, and when it fades out, remove it from array. This way, in the do..while loop, you will check if the item selected is inside the array